# Trying to get the number of Calendar Days/Workdays/Weeks within a set period

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a script that gets the count of Business days, Calendar days and Weekdays within a set period (23rd of Previous month and 23rd of Current month).

I have the following script where I tried to use Worksheet Functions but it doesn't work, I get

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

error, what gives?

```
Sub DayCounts()
    Dim cYear As String
    Dim pMon As String
    Dim cpMon As String
    Dim start_date As String
    Dim end_date As String
    Dim mySh As Worksheet
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set mySh = Sheets("prod_log_manual")

    cYear = Format(Date, yyyy) 'get year
    pMon = Format(Date - 1, mm) 'get previous month
    cMon = Format(Date, mm) 'get current month

    start_date = cYear & pMon & 24 '23th of previous month
    end_date = cYear & cMon & 23 '23rd of current month

    mySh.Range("P7") = wf.NetworkDays(start_date, end_date) 'get number of workdays in period
    mySh.Range("P8") = wf.Day(start_date, end_date) 'get number of calendar days in period
    mySh.Range("P9") = mySh.Range("P8").Value / 7 'get number of weeks within period
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, correct the date collection per [Vityata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448626/vityata)'s response.

You might want to use actual dates, not string concatenations.

```
mySh.Range("P7") = wf.NetworkDays(dateserial(clng(cYear)+cbool(clng(pmon)=12), clng(pmon), 24), dateserial(clng(cYear), clng(cmon), 23)) 'get number of workdays in period
```

NetworkDays is inclusive. Should you be using 23 for both? Shouldn't the previous be 24 or the current be 22?

Comment: Edit: Basically we have a set period every month (24th of last month until the 23th of current month) where I need to get the respective days.

Comment: So each month counts 1 day that is common to either the previous month or the next month.

Comment: Sorry I updated my comment, I got it wrong. It is 24th of previous month to the 23rd of current month.

Comment: Your code runs properly now, but when I try to adapt it to the calendar days I get the correct number but as a negative (-27) `mySh.Range("P6") = wf.Days(DateSerial(CLng(cYear) + CBool(CLng(pMon) = 12), CLng(pMon), 24), DateSerial(CLng(cYear), CLng(cMon), 23))`

Comment: Flip the pmon and cmon date constructions.

Comment: Okay thank you I'll stick with your code as it  seems to be the most straightforward. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The error

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

tells you that the variable `wf` is not set yet, which means you declared it

```
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
```

but it's still empty because you didn't initialize it with

```
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
```

---

This is what you should have done

```
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
mySh.Range("P7") = wf.NetworkDays(start_date, end_date) 'get number of workdays in period
mySh.Range("P8") = wf.Days(start_date, end_date) 'get number of calendar days in period
```

**Note that it is `wf.Days` not `wf.Day` as Jeeped pointed out in the comment.**

or use `WorksheetFunction.` instead of `wf.` or set `WorksheetFunction`

```
mySh.Range("P7") = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(start_date, end_date) 'get number of workdays in period
mySh.Range("P8") = WorksheetFunction.Days(start_date, end_date) 'get number of calendar days in period
```

And probably have a look at Vityata's answer which will solve your next issue you will run into after you solved this one.

Comment: Isn't the function `DAYS(..., ...)` not `DAY(...)` ?

Comment: I set WorksheetFunction as you instructed and added Option Explicit declaring the proper variables but now I get "Unable to get the NetworkDays property of the WorksheetFunction class".

Answer (score 3):

Write `Option Explicit` on the top of the module. Thus, code like:

```
cYear = Format(Date, yyyy) 'get year
pMon = Format(Date - 1, mm) 'get previous month
cMon = Format(Date, mm) 'get current month
```

will start telling you that something is wrong. E.g., `yyyy`, `mm` are not defined as variables, which would give you the idea that they should be either variables or passed as string like this:

`cYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")`

Comment: I have declared cYear as String for example, but I still get the error, what am I doing wrong? I added option explicit and have year as cYear = Format(Date, "yyyy") (declared as String) but now it says "Unable to get the NetworkDays property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Comment: @Rhyfelwr - you should declare the worksheetfunction the way Peh has shown in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `start_date` and  `end_date` as `Date`, instead of `String`, and it will simplify and shorten your code by a lot.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub DayCounts()

    Dim start_date As Date ' use Date variables
    Dim end_date As Date ' use Date variables
    Dim mySh As Worksheet
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set mySh = Sheets("prod_log_manual")

    ' set the worksheetfunction object
    Set wf = WorksheetFunction

    end_date = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 23) ' 23rd of current month
    start_date = DateAdd("m", -1, end_date) ' 23th of previous month

    mySh.Range("P7") = wf.NetworkDays(start_date, end_date) ' get number of workdays in period
    mySh.Range("P8") = wf.Days(start_date, end_date) ' get number of calendar days in period

    mySh.Range("P9") = mySh.Range("P8").Value / 7 'get number of weeks within period

    ' can also use DateDiff with "w", which is weeks as the interval
    mySh.Range("P9") = DateDiff("w", start_date, end_date)

End Sub
```